# Shiny Server can't find package

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I know that I do not have a lot of information here, but I am trying to deploy an app over Shiny Server with the new shinydashboard package.  I have installed shinydashboard,

```
devtools::install_github("rstudio/shinydashboard")
library(shinydashboard)
```

but when I run my app over the server, I get an error saying:

```
"ERROR: there is no package called â€˜shinydashboardâ€™"
```

I have checked and know that the devtools version was installed in the same directory as all of my other packages, so I am not sure what the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to align your `.libPath()` between "your" session what the shiny server sees.  You can actually designate an installation directory when running `install.packages()`, and for this very reason I always do (via a script).

Comment: Thanks.  I did not set up the Shiny Server myself and did not realize that packages also to be uploaded to the server separately.

Answer (score 0):

So, the issue may be that shinyapps.io automatically detects and installs application package dependencies for you. You should not install any packages within your source files. Remove the first line in your code and just leave the `library` and re-run the code and see if it alleviates the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that too, but was getting the same error message.

Comment: Can you please copy the output of `shinyapps::showLogs()` ?